# Glassfish web application not responding

Tags: java, war, glassfish-3

Is there a good reason for a simple web application (packaged as war) not to respond under glassfish 3? I deployed it on a remote server and launching the application from the console simply times out. Everything is telling me the application is deployed and enabled (glassfish console and asadmin commands alike), yet, entering its url gives no response. I checked ufw (OS is Ubuntu) and it is disabled.

Comment: By the way, it works locally on my own machine, I want to deploy it to my real, remote server, however.

Comment: Its a bit misleading to speak of "good" reasons, but a common cause is another internal connection that does not want to succeed and has a high timeout limit. Say a database connection.

Comment: Thanks, @Gimby, you mean it could be a port conflict? So if I create another http listener with a port number I know is not used and connect thru that, it should work? Tried that too...

Comment: It could be a port mapping issue, I just realized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it was a port problem. Entering the world of real servers you suddenly have to take into account that it is one thing what number a port has as a localhost and what number that same port has if accessed remotely. Law of relativity! I had to mess around with the remote server's router to do some port forwarding.

Comment: Its a sobering moment, where you realize that when you start to apply software engineering outside of the protected shell of a development environment you are suddenly faced with a whole slew of problems you can't solve by throwing code or a debugger at it :)

Comment: Yes, @Gimby and I'm glad I could wet my feet in those problems! Buying a real server and deploying it in the wild was a great idea! And it's not too expensive nowadays either.